# Tensorflow.js tf.browser.fromPixels() must be an HTMLVideoElement

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

I am using tensorflow.js in a node + nwjs project and when I give a video element as input to the tensowflow fromPixels method I get this wierd error as output in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels()
> must be either an **HTMLVideoElement**, HTMLImageElement,
> HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData
> in webworker or {data: Uint32Array, width: number, height: number},
> but was **HTMLVideoElement**

So I can't understand what is going wrong...

This line of code that generate the error is:

```
const input_tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(video);
```

The `video` is defined as:

```
export const video = document.getElementById("webcam");
```

That refers to this HTML element:

```
<video id="webcam" autoplay muted></video>
```

Comment: It can be that your element is not yet loaded. What happens when you do `console.log(video) ?`

Comment: I did not think about that...now I check thanks

Comment: I tryied to add the console.log just before the fromPixels call and I get `<video id="webcam" autoplay="" muted=""></video>`
I am confused :/

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution

Comment: That is the problem, video is not loaded yet! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video element has not yet loaded to display the video. The following should execute `fromPixel` only after the video has started loading

```
const videoElement = document.getElementById("webcam");

videoElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', (e) => {
   //Video should now be loaded but we can add a second check

   if(videoElement.readyState >= 3){
       const input_tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(video);
   }

});
```